# express-fileupload - how to allow big files upload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am using express-fileupload npm package for multipart file uploads. I need to upload multiple files and size can be more than default allowed 100kb size. I have also added following config for fileupload to allow big size files but no luck.

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
  }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Please let me know if I am missing any setting.

Answer (score 1):

express-fileupload doesn't have any limitations on the file size by default.
So I can suggest that was could some service limitations which you used.

One more thing that it's recommended to use option useTempFiles for large files.

When useTempFiles is true middleware uses temporary files instead of memory for managing the upload process.

e.g.

```
app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to put bodyParse.json() first to work correctly with JSON and any other form of data (urlencoded and multipart).

`app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`